# Closure Table for users\groups management?

Tags: transitive-closure-table

any of you have ever used Closure Table to represent the hierarchy users groups ?
In all the examples I found online the id of the node is always unique within the structure.

Try to imagine this issue :
In a classic security management in my software I have a list of users and a list of groups, I'd like to make sure that a user can belong to several groups and each group can in turn contain other groups .

Users table :

Id | UserType | Name

( UserType is 0 if the record represents a user , if group 1 )

table UserHC
Id | ParentId | Level

Analyzing the classic command to insert already known that if " MyID " is already present (since the primary key is Id, ParentId ) would not be good .

INSERT INTO UserHC ( [Id], [ParentId], [Level] )
select  {MyID} as [Id], [ParentId], [Level] +1 from UserHC where [Id] = {myid}
UNION ALL
SELECT {MyID}, {myId}  , 0

*Where MyId is new  Users.Id

Before i make a complex analysis I was wondering if any of you have already had a similar requirement and how you resolved it .

thanks

Comment: Which online examples are you mentioning? What exactly is `MyID`? Which SQL dialect / DBMS are you using?